# Some functions that work on Dev don't work in Release

Tags: mysql, laravel, deployment, homestead

I'm finishing a school project that constitutes a big part of my studies, my project is a simple social network developed in `Laravel`.

I'm having trouble getting the same functionality I have in dev on my local homstead instance on release which is a digital ocean droplet running LEMP.

One example is the search option presented to registered users, searching in dev returns other users, wheras searching in release sends you back to the page where you came from.

Another example is the "load more posts" option presented to a registered user when the timeline contains more than 8 posts, to load more than 8 the user must press the "load more" button which will query to posts table for more content.

I though it must be a MySQL configuration error but I'm not sure since users can create posts and follow other users no problem.
Also it's not a Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) misconfiguration since I disabled CSRF middleware and the problem persisted.

I'm not sure what code I should supply to diagnose this error, so any code solicited will be posted.

Here's my github with all relate code anyway: 
[GitHub](https://github.com/E-Chan/instyle/)

Also here's a recording of the error: 
[Video](https://youtu.be/3AWPNHCQhN4)

You can access the site at 
[Live instance of the site](http://www.instyle.social)

Comment: Sharing your code is nice, but the number of people that are going to look at your full code will be very limited, if you can't narrow it down. The usual way is: try to find some minimal code that will reproduce your problem. Try to debug your code: enable error messages; echo every variable on the page; echo something for each "if-then-else"-path; you can then e.g. ask what configuration or reason could result in that specific different behaviour. It is probably a configuration or a permission problem, or maybe you didn't allow cookies. Check php version and apache config.

Comment: Ditto @Solarflare...  posting a [minimal, complete and verifiable example] is an SO mantra/golden rule (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I've tried to pinpoint a code segment that might help diagnose the error, and i simply can't figure out where it's coming from making it very hard to post some code, that's why I've considered recording the error as an example.

Comment: Should I maybe post my nginx and php configuration files?

Comment: You know your code. We don't. To understand your code, we would need about the same time you spend writing it. And it might not even be in your code, since it runs locally - although by randomly clicking on the two only functions of your live site, I found two not working functions, so it might be your code after all. What you can do: a) compare the configuration of live and local server. b) [Debug your code](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3): e.g. add as many `log::debug` as you can. Start with the button you press and add them everywhere. Do that on both servers. Find differences. Show us these.